# Choosing product attributes in frontend without order

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute, frontend

When a customer wants to buy a T-Shirt he has to choose the color first and then he can choose the size. But I want him to do this also the other way around. So that he can choose the color or size first. At now, he is not able to choose the size before he chose the color.

Comment: Are you asking if you can let the customer choose any attribute first then have the other attribute filter off of that one?

Comment: With Magento 1.9.1 you shouldn't have anymore this problem thanks to the new Configurable Swatches feature.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Galdoran and welcome to MageOverflow.

What you want is no problem, you just have to implement the logic for this which lays in `js/varien/configurable.js` again, but the other way around.

Magento generates a data structure with all possible ways if you choose one attribute after another.

If you want *ALL* combinations, this is a lot, so not practical.

I recommend to not do this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In this case I only want the combination between size and color. Is this realizable? Can you give me a short instruction on how to do this in detail?